# Hide div unless it has a source from onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

How do I only show the `.modal-item` div's inside of the `.modal` container if there is a source that came from clicking on the `.item`?

Example: If I clicked the first item, only the `#item-img` div would show because it's the only div that received a source from the function. Both `#item-text`, `#item-sub-text` will remain `hidden` because they had no source.

```js
$(".container").on("click", ".item", function() {
  var t = $(this).closest(".item");
  $("#item-text").text(t.find(".item-text").text());
    $("#item-sub-text").text(t.find(".item-sub-text").text());
   var a = t.find(".item-img").attr("src");
 $("#item-img").css("background-image", 'url("' + a + '")'); 
});
```

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
}
.container,
.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.modal {

  background: #eee
}
.item,
.modal-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item-img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
}
#item-img {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="item-img" src="https://www.oysterdiving.com/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-sub-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="item-img" src="">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-sub-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="item-img" src="">
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p class="item-sub-text">Sub</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-item" id="item-img"></div>
    <div class="modal-item" id="item-text">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-item" id="item-sub-text">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hide()` or `show()` function jQuery

```
function checkShowHide(text, ele) {
  if (text !== '') {
    $(ele).show();
    $(ele).text(text);
  } else {
    $(ele).hide();
  }
}
$(".container").on("click", ".item", function() {
  var t = $(this).closest(".item");
  var itemText = t.find(".item-text").text();
  var itemSubText = t.find(".item-sub-text").text()
  var itemBG = t.find(".item-img").attr("src");
  checkShowHide(itemText, '#item-text');
  checkShowHide(itemSubText, '#item-sub-text');

    var a = t.find(".item-img").attr("src");
  if (a !== '') {
    $("#item-img").show();
    $("#item-img").css("background-image", 'url("' + a + '")'); 
  } else {
    $("#item-img").hide();
  }

});
```

Here is my solution. You can check in my codepen: https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/pLWrxg